How to link two files together in Processing IDE?
I'm making a project here consisting of a 3D Solar System App.
So my app has a main screen, and after touching the red box, it will redirect to the 3D Solar System Model.
The problem here is that my codes are separated from each other.
Here is my code:
For the home screen:
StateInterface currentState = new StateHome();

// -------------------------------------------------

void setup() {
  // init (runs only once)
  fullScreen(OPENGL);
} // func

void draw() {
  // runs on and on
  currentState.showState();
}

// ----------------------------------------
// keyboard input

void keyPressed() {
  currentState.keyPressedState();
}

//----------------------------------------

void mousePressed() {
  currentState.mousePressedState();
}

// ===============================================================================================

class StateHome implements StateInterface {
  // Game
  void showState() {
    // Game
    background(11);
    fill(244, 3, 3); // red
    text ("Welcome to Solar System Generator", 850, 100);

    //
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 2, 2) ;
    rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    fill(255, 2, 255) ;
    // rect(300, 100, 100, 100);

    if (mouseX > 100 &&
      mouseX < 100 + 100  &&
      mouseY > 100   &&
      mouseY < 100 + 100) {
      println ("collide");
      currentState = new statePause();
    }
  } // func

  void keyPressedState() {
    if (key == CODED)
    {
      if (keyCode == UP) {
        //
      } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        //
      }

      if (keyCode == LEFT) {
        //
      } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
        //
      } else {
        // do nothing
      } // else
    } //  if (key == CODED) {
    else
    {
      // not CODED ----------------------
      if (key == 'p') {
        // Pause
        currentState =  new statePause();
      } else {
        // do nothing
      } // else
    } // else not CODED
  } // func

  void mousePressedState() {
    // Game
    println("mouse 1");
  }//func
}//class

// ===========================================================================================

class statePause implements StateInterface {
  // My Solar System Generator that will be here
}

interface StateInterface {

  // Let's abstract

  // Let's abstract display()
  void showState();
  void keyPressedState();
  void mousePressedState();
}

For the Solar System Generator:
import peasy.*; 

PeasyCam cam;
ArrayList<Planet> planets;
float fmax = 0;
ArrayList<PVector> stars;
float rotate;
float radius = 250;
float camheight = 1000;
float fov;
float cameraZ;
float dis1;
int steps = 400000;

int p;

PImage sun, mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune;

void setup() {
  //size(800, 600, OPENGL);
  fullScreen(OPENGL);
  frameRate(100);
  

  sun = loadImage("Sun.jpg");
  mercury = loadImage("Mercury.jpg");
  venus = loadImage("Venus.jpg");
  earth = loadImage("Earth.jpg");
  mars = loadImage("Mars.jpg");
  jupiter = loadImage("Jupiter.jpg");
  saturn = loadImage("Saturn.jpg");
  uranus = loadImage("Uranus.jpg");
  neptune = loadImage("Neptune.jpg");
  
  p = 0;

  fov = radians(70);

  perspective(fov, float(width)/float(height), 1, 9999999);

  cam = new PeasyCam(this, width/2, height/2, 0, 1000);
  cam.setMinimumDistance(21);

  planets = new ArrayList<Planet>();

  planets.add(new Planet("Sonne", 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 333054, 255, 230, 0, 1, 1000, 0, sun));

  planets.add(new Planet("Mercury", 62.543, 7, 0, 0.205, 8, 0.055, 132, 132, 132, 45, 13, 10, mercury)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Venus", 145.763, 3.4, 177, 0.007, 12, 0.8149, 197, 133, 40, 50, 28, 5, venus)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Earth", 200, 0, 23.4, 0.017, 13, 1, 84, 101, 130, 50, 48, 0.1, earth));
  planets.add(new Planet("Mars", 280.9, 1.9, 6.7, 0.094, 9, 0.1069, 183, 99, 72, 60, 76, 0.1, mars)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Jupiter", 1006.798, 1.3, 25.2, 0.049, 40, 317, 167, 161, 150, 80, 350, 0.05, jupiter)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Saturn", 1839.02, 2.5, 3.1, 0.057, 32, 95, 208, 193, 163, 100, 700, 0.05, saturn)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Uranus", 3727.1, 0.8, 26.7, 0.046, 60, 14, 155, 203, 210, 132, 1450, 0.07, uranus)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Neptune", 6042.8, 1.8, 97.8, 0.011, 70, 17, 45, 52, 132, 183, 2000, 0.08, neptune)); 
  //planets.add(new Planet("Pluto", -5032.3589395, 0, 0, 0, -0.19226, 0, 15, 0.10699933, 250, 200, 50)); 

  background(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    pre(i);
  }
}

void draw() {  
  background(0);

  //pushMatrix();
  //translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
  //stroke(0, 0, 255);
  //line(300, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0);
  //stroke(0, 255, 0);
  //line(0, 330, 0, -0, -100, 0);
  //stroke(255, 0, 0);
  //line(0, 0, 300, 0, 0, -100);
  //popMatrix();

  float dis = (float) cam.getDistance();
  if (dis > 50000) dis = 50000;
  if (dis < 21) dis = 21;
  dis1 = map(dis, 21, 50000, 0, 255);
  fov = radians(log1(dis1));
  perspective(fov, float(width)/float(height), 1, 9999999);

  pushMatrix();
  float[] campos = cam.getPosition();
  translate(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2]);
  translate(-campos[0], -campos[1], -campos[2]);
  popMatrix();

  for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
    planet1.grav(planet1, planets);
  }

  for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
    planet1.updateVel();
  }

  Planet plan = planets.get(0);
  Planet plan2 = planets.get(p);
  //camera(width/2, /*(height/2)*/ + map(mouseY, 0, height, -1000, 1000), 1000, width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 0, 1);

  pushMatrix();
  translate((width/2) - plan2.pos.x, (height/2) - plan2.pos.y, 0 - plan2.pos.z);
  for (int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++) {
    Planet plan1 = planets.get(i);
    if (i != 0) plan1.light(plan);
    plan1.show();
  }
  popMatrix();
}

void pre(int i) {
  for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
    planet1.grav(planet1, planets);
  }

  for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
    planet1.updateVel1(i);
  }
}

float log1(float a) {
  float a2 = 2100 / (30 + 70 * exp(0.021 * -a));
  return a2;
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'w'){ 
    p++;
    if (p > planets.size()-1) p = 0;
  }
  if (key == 's'){ 
    p--;
    if (p < 0) p = planets.size()-1;
  }

}

class Planet {
  PVector pos;
  PVector vel;
  PVector acc;
  float radius;
  float mass;
  float r, g, b;
  int mod;
  PVector currVel;
  String name;
  ArrayList<PVector> posStore;
  float dis;
  int traillength;
  float rotation;
  float rot;
  float winkelPole;

  float Grav = 0.0002;

  PShape planet;

  Planet(String name, float dis, float incl, float winkelPole, float ecc, float r, float m, float re, float g, float b, int traillength, int mod, float rot, PImage img) {
    float vz;
    if (dis != 0) vz = sqrt((Grav * 333054) / dis);
    else vz = 0;
    vz = vz * (1 + (ecc/2));

    this.pos = new PVector(dis, 0, 0);
    this.vel = new PVector(0, 0, vz);
    this.pos.x = dis * cos(radians(incl));
    this.pos.y = (dis * sin(radians(incl))) *-1;
    float hyp = vz / cos(radians(incl));
    this.vel.y = sin(radians(incl)) * hyp;
    this.vel.setMag(vz*-1);

    this.winkelPole = winkelPole;
    this.rotation = rot;
    this.mod = mod;
    this.radius = r;
    this.mass = /*PI * sq(r)*/ m;
    this.r = re;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
    this.currVel = new PVector(this.vel.x, this.vel.y, this.vel.z);
    this.name = name;
    this.traillength = traillength;

    this.posStore = new ArrayList<PVector>(traillength);
    for (int i = 0; i < traillength; i++) {
      posStore.add(new PVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z));
    }

    planet = createShape(SPHERE, r);
    planet.setTexture(img);
    planet.setStroke(0);
  }

  void grav(Planet planet1, ArrayList<Planet> planets) {
    for (Planet planet2 : planets) {
      if (planet1 == planet2) continue;
      PVector forceDir = PVector.sub(planet2.pos, planet1.pos); 
      float d = forceDir.magSq();
      forceDir.normalize();
      PVector f = forceDir.mult(Grav * planet2.mass / d);
      currVel = planet1.vel.add(f);
    }
  }

  void updateVel() {
    this.pos.add(this.currVel);
    if (frameCount % mod == 0) posStore.add(0, new PVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z));
    if ( posStore.size() > traillength) posStore.remove(traillength);
  }

  void updateVel1(int i) {
    this.pos.add(this.currVel);
    if (i % mod == 0) posStore.add(0, new PVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z));
    if ( posStore.size() > traillength) posStore.remove(traillength);
  }

  void show() {
    for (int i = 0; i < posStore.size()-2; i++) {
      PVector p1 = posStore.get(i);
      PVector p2 = posStore.get(i+1);
      stroke(this.r, this.g, this.b);
      line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z, p2.x, p2.y, p2.z);
    }

    noStroke();
    fill(r, g, b);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
    if (rotation != 0) {
      if (rot > 1000000) rot = 0;
      rot = rot + (0.1 / rotation);
      rotateX(radians(winkelPole));
      rotateY(radians(rot));
    }
    //specular(r*1.5, g*1.5, b*1.5);     
    //shininess(5);
    //emissive(r*0.2, g*0.2, b*0.2);
    shape(planet);
    popMatrix();
  }

  void light(Planet plan) {
    lightSpecular(0, 0, 0);
    pointLight(120, 120, 110, plan.pos.x, plan.pos.y, plan.pos.z);
  }
}

So, I tried to directly combine the codes together:
import peasy.*; 

PeasyCam cam;
ArrayList<Planet> planets;
float fmax = 0;
ArrayList<PVector> stars;
float rotate;
float radius = 250;
float camheight = 1000;
float fov;
float cameraZ;
float dis1;
int steps = 400000;

int p;

PImage sun, mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune;

StateInterface currentState = new StateHome();

// -------------------------------------------------

void setup() {
  // init (runs only once)
  fullScreen(OPENGL);
} // func

void draw() {
  // runs on and on
  currentState.showState();
}

// ----------------------------------------
// keyboard input

void keyPressed() {
  currentState.keyPressedState();
}

//----------------------------------------

void mousePressed() {
  currentState.mousePressedState();
}

// ===============================================================================================

class StateHome implements StateInterface {
  // Game
  void showState() {
    // Game
    background(11);
    fill(244, 3, 3); // red
    text ("Welcome to Solar System Generator", 850, 100);

    //
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 2, 2) ;
    rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    fill(255, 2, 255) ;
    // rect(300, 100, 100, 100);

    if (mouseX > 100 &&
      mouseX < 100 + 100  &&
      mouseY > 100   &&
      mouseY < 100 + 100) {
      println ("collide");
      currentState = new statePause();
    }
  } // func

  void keyPressedState() {
    if (key == CODED)
    {
      if (keyCode == UP) {
        //
      } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        //
      }

      if (keyCode == LEFT) {
        //
      } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
        //
      } else {
        // do nothing
      } // else
    } //  if (key == CODED) {
    else
    {
      // not CODED ----------------------
      if (key == 'p') {
        // Pause
        currentState =  new statePause();
      } else {
        // do nothing
      } // else
    } // else not CODED
  } // func

  void mousePressedState() {
    // Game
    println("mouse 1");
  }//func
}//class

// ===========================================================================================

class statePause implements StateInterface {
  sun = loadImage("Sun.jpg");
  mercury = loadImage("Mercury.jpg");
  venus = loadImage("Venus.jpg");
  earth = loadImage("Earth.jpg");
  mars = loadImage("Mars.jpg");
  jupiter = loadImage("Jupiter.jpg");
  saturn = loadImage("Saturn.jpg");
  uranus = loadImage("Uranus.jpg");
  neptune = loadImage("Neptune.jpg");
  
  p = 0;

  fov = radians(70);

  perspective(fov, float(width)/float(height), 1, 9999999);

  cam = new PeasyCam(this, width/2, height/2, 0, 1000);
  cam.setMinimumDistance(21);

  planets = new ArrayList<Planet>();

  planets.add(new Planet("Sonne", 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 333054, 255, 230, 0, 1, 1000, 0, sun));

  planets.add(new Planet("Mercury", 62.543, 7, 0, 0.205, 8, 0.055, 132, 132, 132, 45, 13, 10, mercury)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Venus", 145.763, 3.4, 177, 0.007, 12, 0.8149, 197, 133, 40, 50, 28, 5, venus)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Earth", 200, 0, 23.4, 0.017, 13, 1, 84, 101, 130, 50, 48, 0.1, earth));
  planets.add(new Planet("Mars", 280.9, 1.9, 6.7, 0.094, 9, 0.1069, 183, 99, 72, 60, 76, 0.1, mars)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Jupiter", 1006.798, 1.3, 25.2, 0.049, 40, 317, 167, 161, 150, 80, 350, 0.05, jupiter)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Saturn", 1839.02, 2.5, 3.1, 0.057, 32, 95, 208, 193, 163, 100, 700, 0.05, saturn)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Uranus", 3727.1, 0.8, 26.7, 0.046, 60, 14, 155, 203, 210, 132, 1450, 0.07, uranus)); 
  planets.add(new Planet("Neptune", 6042.8, 1.8, 97.8, 0.011, 70, 17, 45, 52, 132, 183, 2000, 0.08, neptune)); 
  //planets.add(new Planet("Pluto", -5032.3589395, 0, 0, 0, -0.19226, 0, 15, 0.10699933, 250, 200, 50)); 

  background(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    pre(i);
  }
}

void draw() {  
  background(0);

  //pushMatrix();
  //translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
  //stroke(0, 0, 255);
  //line(300, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0);
  //stroke(0, 255, 0);
  //line(0, 330, 0, -0, -100, 0);
  //stroke(255, 0, 0);
  //line(0, 0, 300, 0, 0, -100);
  //popMatrix();

  float dis = (float) cam.getDistance();
  if (dis > 50000) dis = 50000;
  if (dis < 21) dis = 21;
  dis1 = map(dis, 21, 50000, 0, 255);
  fov = radians(log1(dis1));
  perspective(fov, float(width)/float(height), 1, 9999999);

  pushMatrix();
  float[] campos = cam.getPosition();
  translate(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2]);
  translate(-campos[0], -campos[1], -campos[2]);
  popMatrix();

  for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
    planet1.grav(planet1, planets);
  }

  for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
    planet1.updateVel();
  }

  Planet plan = planets.get(0);
  Planet plan2 = planets.get(p);
  //camera(width/2, /*(height/2)*/ + map(mouseY, 0, height, -1000, 1000), 1000, width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 0, 1);

  pushMatrix();
  translate((width/2) - plan2.pos.x, (height/2) - plan2.pos.y, 0 - plan2.pos.z);
  for (int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++) {
    Planet plan1 = planets.get(i);
    if (i != 0) plan1.light(plan);
    plan1.show();
  }
  popMatrix();
}

void pre(int i) {
  for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
    planet1.grav(planet1, planets);
  }

  for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
    planet1.updateVel1(i);
  }
}

float log1(float a) {
  float a2 = 2100 / (30 + 70 * exp(0.021 * -a));
  return a2;
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'w'){ 
    p++;
    if (p > planets.size()-1) p = 0;
  }
  if (key == 's'){ 
    p--;
    if (p < 0) p = planets.size()-1;
  }

}

class Planet {
  PVector pos;
  PVector vel;
  PVector acc;
  float radius;
  float mass;
  float r, g, b;
  int mod;
  PVector currVel;
  String name;
  ArrayList<PVector> posStore;
  float dis;
  int traillength;
  float rotation;
  float rot;
  float winkelPole;

  float Grav = 0.0002;

  PShape planet;

  Planet(String name, float dis, float incl, float winkelPole, float ecc, float r, float m, float re, float g, float b, int traillength, int mod, float rot, PImage img) {
    float vz;
    if (dis != 0) vz = sqrt((Grav * 333054) / dis);
    else vz = 0;
    vz = vz * (1 + (ecc/2));

    this.pos = new PVector(dis, 0, 0);
    this.vel = new PVector(0, 0, vz);
    this.pos.x = dis * cos(radians(incl));
    this.pos.y = (dis * sin(radians(incl))) *-1;
    float hyp = vz / cos(radians(incl));
    this.vel.y = sin(radians(incl)) * hyp;
    this.vel.setMag(vz*-1);

    this.winkelPole = winkelPole;
    this.rotation = rot;
    this.mod = mod;
    this.radius = r;
    this.mass = /*PI * sq(r)*/ m;
    this.r = re;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
    this.currVel = new PVector(this.vel.x, this.vel.y, this.vel.z);
    this.name = name;
    this.traillength = traillength;

    this.posStore = new ArrayList<PVector>(traillength);
    for (int i = 0; i < traillength; i++) {
      posStore.add(new PVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z));
    }

    planet = createShape(SPHERE, r);
    planet.setTexture(img);
    planet.setStroke(0);
  }

  void grav(Planet planet1, ArrayList<Planet> planets) {
    for (Planet planet2 : planets) {
      if (planet1 == planet2) continue;
      PVector forceDir = PVector.sub(planet2.pos, planet1.pos); 
      float d = forceDir.magSq();
      forceDir.normalize();
      PVector f = forceDir.mult(Grav * planet2.mass / d);
      currVel = planet1.vel.add(f);
    }
  }

  void updateVel() {
    this.pos.add(this.currVel);
    if (frameCount % mod == 0) posStore.add(0, new PVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z));
    if ( posStore.size() > traillength) posStore.remove(traillength);
  }

  void updateVel1(int i) {
    this.pos.add(this.currVel);
    if (i % mod == 0) posStore.add(0, new PVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z));
    if ( posStore.size() > traillength) posStore.remove(traillength);
  }

  void show() {
    for (int i = 0; i < posStore.size()-2; i++) {
      PVector p1 = posStore.get(i);
      PVector p2 = posStore.get(i+1);
      stroke(this.r, this.g, this.b);
      line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z, p2.x, p2.y, p2.z);
    }

    noStroke();
    fill(r, g, b);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
    if (rotation != 0) {
      if (rot > 1000000) rot = 0;
      rot = rot + (0.1 / rotation);
      rotateX(radians(winkelPole));
      rotateY(radians(rot));
    }
    //specular(r*1.5, g*1.5, b*1.5);     
    //shininess(5);
    //emissive(r*0.2, g*0.2, b*0.2);
    shape(planet);
    popMatrix();
  }

  void light(Planet plan) {
    lightSpecular(0, 0, 0);
    pointLight(120, 120, 110, plan.pos.x, plan.pos.y, plan.pos.z);
  }
}
}

interface StateInterface {

  // Let's abstract

  // Let's abstract display()
  void showState();
  void keyPressedState();
  void mousePressedState();
}
//

Which is a cause a bunch of mess, and it didn't work.
Hence, I would like to know how to link the files together in Processing IDE.
Here is the link to the pictures for the planets:
https://planetpixelemporium.com/

As I stated in the question.
After my mouse touch the red rectangle, I want it to generate the 3D Solar System for me.
Question is HOW?

Unfortunately I can't commit the time for a detailed explantion. I hope a comment with a few pointers can help: 1. tidy up a bit / move each state to it's own tab in the Processing IDE and make new tab for the Planet class. 2. create a basic StatePause class and in the implementation methods add println statements to check that the state management works as expected. (e.g. when the state is set to your state, check showState() gets called in draw(), keyPressedState() gets called in keyPress() and mousePressedState() gets called in mousePressed()). Then, one section at a time...

...add your code into the StatePause class. 1. the items you had in setup() will go into the StatePause constructor, what you had in draw() in your sketch becomes showState(), what you had in keyPressed() moves to keyPressedState() and mousePressedState() remains unchanged. You can see a similar approach in this answer

Will check later.
Bear in mind that I might ask more question regarding this project.

Sure thing. You can of course post more questions regarding the project.
Breaking the project down into smaller easier to tackle steps is a great idea.

Perhaps the following source code will get you started.  I added another function to your StateHome class called 'showGame()' and added a global boolean called 'startGame'.  The boolean is triggered by a mouse press on your home window (red square is non-functional); draw() then checks to see if the boolean is true or false.  If it's true the solar system is shown.  The planet class needs to be under its own tab to simplify your code.  OpenGL has been deprecated so I used P3D as the renderer.  Note that I also used .png images instead of .jpg but you may use whatever you have; change the code if necessary.
import peasy.*;

PeasyCam cam;
ArrayList<Planet> planets;
float fmax = 0;
ArrayList<PVector> stars;
float rotate;
float radius = 250;
float camheight = 1000;
float fov;
float cameraZ;
float dis1;
int steps = 400000;

int p;

PImage sun, mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune;

StateInterface currentState = new StateHome();
boolean startGame = false;

void pre(int i) {
  for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
    planet1.grav(planet1, planets);
  }

  for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
    planet1.updateVel1(i);
  }
}

float log1(float a) {
  float a2 = 2100 / (30 + 70 * exp(0.021 * -a));
  return a2;
}

void setup() {
  fullScreen(P3D);
  sun = loadImage("Sun.png");
  mercury = loadImage("Mercury.png");
  venus = loadImage("Venus.png");
  earth = loadImage("Earth.png");
  mars = loadImage("Mars.png");
  jupiter = loadImage("Jupiter.png");
  saturn = loadImage("Saturn.png");
  uranus = loadImage("Uranus.png");
  neptune = loadImage("Neptune.png");

  p = 0;

  fov = radians(70);

  perspective(fov, float(width)/float(height), 1, 9999999);

  cam = new PeasyCam(this, width/2, height/2, 0, 1000);
  cam.setMinimumDistance(21);

  planets = new ArrayList<Planet>();

  planets.add(new Planet("Sonne", 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 333054, 255, 230, 0, 1, 1000, 0, sun));
  planets.add(new Planet("Mercury", 62.543, 7, 0, 0.205, 8, 0.055, 132, 132, 132, 45, 13, 10, mercury));
  planets.add(new Planet("Venus", 145.763, 3.4, 177, 0.007, 12, 0.8149, 197, 133, 40, 50, 28, 5, venus));
  planets.add(new Planet("Earth", 200, 0, 23.4, 0.017, 13, 1, 84, 101, 130, 50, 48, 0.1, earth));
  planets.add(new Planet("Mars", 280.9, 1.9, 6.7, 0.094, 9, 0.1069, 183, 99, 72, 60, 76, 0.1, mars));
  planets.add(new Planet("Jupiter", 1006.798, 1.3, 25.2, 0.049, 40, 317, 167, 161, 150, 80, 350, 0.05, jupiter));
  planets.add(new Planet("Saturn", 1839.02, 2.5, 3.1, 0.057, 32, 95, 208, 193, 163, 100, 700, 0.05, saturn));
  planets.add(new Planet("Uranus", 3727.1, 0.8, 26.7, 0.046, 60, 14, 155, 203, 210, 132, 1450, 0.07, uranus));
  planets.add(new Planet("Neptune", 6042.8, 1.8, 97.8, 0.011, 70, 17, 45, 52, 132, 183, 2000, 0.08, neptune));
  //planets.add(new Planet("Pluto", -5032.3589395, 0, 0, 0, -0.19226, 0, 15, 0.10699933, 250, 200, 50));

  background(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    pre(i);
  }
}

void draw() {
  if (startGame) {
    currentState.showGame();
  } else {
    currentState.showState();
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  currentState.keyPressedState();
  if (key == 'w') {
    p++;
    if (p > planets.size()-1) p = 0;
  }
  if (key == 's') {
    p--;
    if (p < 0) p = planets.size()-1;
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  currentState.mousePressedState();
}

class StateHome implements StateInterface {
  
  void showState() {
    background(11);
    fill(244, 3, 3); // red
    textSize(48);
    text ("Welcome to Solar System Generator", 850, 100);   
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 2, 2) ;
    rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    fill(255, 2, 255) ;

    if (mouseX > 100 &&
      mouseX < 100 + 100  &&
      mouseY > 100   &&
      mouseY < 100 + 100) {
      println ("button pressed.");
      currentState = new StatePause();
    }
  }

  void showGame() {
    startGame = true;
    background(0);

    float dis = (float) cam.getDistance();
    if (dis > 50000) dis = 50000;
    if (dis < 21) dis = 21;
    dis1 = map(dis, 21, 50000, 0, 255);
    fov = radians(log1(dis1));
    perspective(fov, float(width)/float(height), 1, 9999999);

    pushMatrix();
    float[] campos = cam.getPosition();
    translate(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2]);
    translate(-campos[0], -campos[1], -campos[2]);
    popMatrix();

    for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
      planet1.grav(planet1, planets);
    }

    for (Planet planet1 : planets) {
      planet1.updateVel();
    }

    Planet plan = planets.get(0);
    Planet plan2 = planets.get(p);
    //camera(width/2, /*(height/2)*/ + map(mouseY, 0, height, -1000, 1000), 1000, width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 0, 1);

    pushMatrix();
    translate((width/2) - plan2.pos.x, (height/2) - plan2.pos.y, 0 - plan2.pos.z);
    for (int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++) {
      Planet plan1 = planets.get(i);
      if (i != 0) plan1.light(plan);
      plan1.show();
    }
    popMatrix();
  }

  void keyPressedState() {
    if (key == CODED) {
      if (keyCode == UP) {
        //
      } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        //
      }

      if (keyCode == LEFT) {
        //
      } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
        //
      } else {
        // do nothing
      } // else
    } //  if (key == CODED) {
    else
    {
      // not CODED ----------------------
      if (key == 'p') {
        // Pause
        currentState =  new StatePause();
      } else {
        // do nothing
      } // else
    } // else not CODED
  } // func

  void mousePressedState() {
    // Game
    println("mouse 1");
    if(!startGame){
    currentState.showGame();
    }
  }//func
}//class

class StatePause implements StateInterface {

  StatePause() {
  }

  void showState() {
  }

  void showGame() {
  }

  void keyPressedState() {
  }

  void mousePressedState() {
  }

}

interface StateInterface {

  void showState();
  void showGame();
  void keyPressedState();
  void mousePressedState();
}


Planet class under separate tab:
class Planet {
  PVector pos;
  PVector vel;
  PVector acc;
  float radius;
  float mass;
  float r, g, b;
  int mod;
  PVector currVel;
  String name;
  ArrayList<PVector> posStore;
  float dis;
  int traillength;
  float rotation;
  float rot;
  float winkelPole;

  float Grav = 0.0002;

  PShape planet;

  Planet(String name, float dis, float incl, float winkelPole, float ecc, float r, float m, float re, float g, float b, int traillength, int mod, float rot, PImage img) {
    float vz;
    if (dis != 0) vz = sqrt((Grav * 333054) / dis);
    else vz = 0;
    vz = vz * (1 + (ecc/2));

    this.pos = new PVector(dis, 0, 0);
    this.vel = new PVector(0, 0, vz);
    this.pos.x = dis * cos(radians(incl));
    this.pos.y = (dis * sin(radians(incl))) *-1;
    float hyp = vz / cos(radians(incl));
    this.vel.y = sin(radians(incl)) * hyp;
    this.vel.setMag(vz*-1);

    this.winkelPole = winkelPole;
    this.rotation = rot;
    this.mod = mod;
    this.radius = r;
    this.mass = /*PI * sq(r)*/ m;
    this.r = re;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
    this.currVel = new PVector(this.vel.x, this.vel.y, this.vel.z);
    this.name = name;
    this.traillength = traillength;

    this.posStore = new ArrayList<PVector>(traillength);
    for (int i = 0; i < traillength; i++) {
      posStore.add(new PVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z));
    }

    planet = createShape(SPHERE, r);
    planet.setTexture(img);
    planet.setStroke(0);
  }

  void grav(Planet planet1, ArrayList<Planet> planets) {
    for (Planet planet2 : planets) {
      if (planet1 == planet2) continue;
      PVector forceDir = PVector.sub(planet2.pos, planet1.pos); 
      float d = forceDir.magSq();
      forceDir.normalize();
      PVector f = forceDir.mult(Grav * planet2.mass / d);
      currVel = planet1.vel.add(f);
    }
  }

  void updateVel() {
    this.pos.add(this.currVel);
    if (frameCount % mod == 0) posStore.add(0, new PVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z));
    if ( posStore.size() > traillength) posStore.remove(traillength);
  }

  void updateVel1(int i) {
    this.pos.add(this.currVel);
    if (i % mod == 0) posStore.add(0, new PVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z));
    if ( posStore.size() > traillength) posStore.remove(traillength);
  }

  void show() {
    for (int i = 0; i < posStore.size()-2; i++) {
      PVector p1 = posStore.get(i);
      PVector p2 = posStore.get(i+1);
      stroke(this.r, this.g, this.b);
      line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z, p2.x, p2.y, p2.z);
    }

    noStroke();
    fill(r, g, b);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
    if (rotation != 0) {
      if (rot > 1000000) rot = 0;
      rot = rot + (0.1 / rotation);
      rotateX(radians(winkelPole));
      rotateY(radians(rot));
    }
    //specular(r*1.5, g*1.5, b*1.5);     
    //shininess(5);
    //emissive(r*0.2, g*0.2, b*0.2);
    shape(planet);
    popMatrix();
  }

  void light(Planet plan) {
    lightSpecular(0, 0, 0);
    pointLight(120, 120, 110, plan.pos.x, plan.pos.y, plan.pos.z);
  }
}

Addendum:
The following is source code for a simple app capable of changing screens for multiple games:
boolean startHome = true;
boolean startGame1 = false;
boolean startGame2 = false;
boolean startGame3 = false;

void setup() {
  fullScreen(P3D);
}

void draw() {
  if (startHome) {
    showHome();
  }
  if (startGame1) {
    showGame1();
  }
  if (startGame2) {
    showGame2();
  }
  if (startGame3) {
    showGame3();
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == '0') {
    startHome = true;
    startGame1 = false;
    startGame2 = false;
    startGame3 = false;
  }
  if (key == '1') {
    startHome = false;
    startGame1 = true;
    startGame2 = false;
    startGame3 = false;
  }
  if (key == '2') {
    startHome = false;
    startGame1 = false;
    startGame2 = true;
    startGame3 = false;
  }
  if (key == '3') {
    startHome = false;
    startGame1 = false;
    startGame2 = false;
    startGame3 = true;
  }
}

void showHome() {
  background(209);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  textSize(42);
  textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
  text ("Welcome to Solar System Generator \n Home = key '0' \n Game 1 = key '1' \n"
  + " Game 2 = key '2' \n Game 3 = key '3' \n Cmd-Q to Quit", width/2, height/2);
}

void showGame1() {
  background(255, 0, 0);
}

void showGame2() {
  background(0, 255, 0);
}

void showGame3() {
  background(0, 0, 255);
}



I believe there are some errors?
It says that Incomplete statement or extra code near ‘extraneous input '' expecting {'color', 'abstract', 'boolean', 'byte', 'char', 'class', 'double', 'enum', 'final', 'float', 'import', 'int', 'interface', 'long', 'native', 'private', 'protected', 'public', 'short', 'static', 'strictfp', 'synchronized', 'transient', 'var', 'void', 'volatile', '{', '}', ';', '<', '@', IDENTIFIER}’?

Runs ok here.  You may have missed a curly brace when you copy/pasted.

Can you assist me with adding another solar system into the simulator?
My goal here is to run multiple systems inside my simulator.
I think all I have to do is just add another tab and link them like the way you did, right?

You should be able to use the same planet class multiple times. Try creating a 'showGame2()' function and add the drawing code like you did for game1. You'll have to figure out some way to call the different games other than a mouseClick, perhaps some unique key presses.  See edited answer for example code.

Will try. Thank you!!

I tried to create two Solar System first, but it shows an error stating that CAN CREATE ONLY 8 LIGHTS. What does it means?

Also, The systems won't have the same planets.
Do I need to open a new tab and write a new code for the new system?

8 lights error is due to calling Planet class twice.  If you want multiple planet systems then you may need to create a separate tab for each system. I haven't tried it.

Can you try it?
I am a bit stuck again..

I added a solar system to each game screen and it works as expected. The problem that you will face is that each 'game' shows the same solar system even though I had three Planet tabs.  It appears to repeatedly use the class from tab1 because that's the only class that was instantiated.  To get variability you will have to make each solar system unique and instantiate each one and keep track of the changes made to each by the app's player.

Start with something simple; complex apps arise from simple apps.  Take the addendum from the answer post and add three classes to it, e.g., Rectangle, Triangle, and Polygon.  Have a display function for each class.  In the main portion of the app instantiate each class, eg myClass = new MyClass().  Under each game call myClass.display() and see if you show the three shapes by selecting each of the three 'games'.

Alright, what if I decides to put all systems in one screen?
Would that be easier or harder?

Probably harder;  not to mention you're using the P3D renderer with a camera.  I have no experience doing that in a Processing window.

In that case, how do I remove the restrictions of the 8 lights error? I'll just directly add the planets onto the current Solar system. Besides, I also wants to show text besides the planets. Is it possible?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
